# Power BI Dax calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

Table: DIM_REQTRANS

| REQDATEMONTHYEAR | REFTYPEENUM | REQQTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Back Order | Demand Forecast | 0 |
| Back Order | Sales Order | 0 |
| Back Order | On-Hand | 3,420,392 |
| Back Order | Planned Batch Order | 0 |
| Back Order | Production | 0 |
| Back Order | Projected On hand Stock |  |
| Apr-2023 | Demand Forecast | 0 |
| Apr-2023 | Sales Order | 258,480 |
| Apr-2023 | On-Hand |  |
| Apr-2023 | Planned Batch Order | 0 |
| Apr-2023 | Production | 247,744 |
| Apr-2023 | Projected On hand Stock |  |
| May-2023 | Demand Forecast | 0 |
| May-2023 | Sales Order | 3,380,080 |
| May-2023 | On-Hand |  |
| May-2023 | Planned Batch Order | 248,256 |
| May-2023 | Production | 3,477,168 |
| May-2023 | Projected On hand Stock |  |
| May-2023 | Demand Forecast | 617,837 |
| May-2023 | Sales Order | 3,908,480 |
| May-2023 | On-Hand |  |
| May-2023 | Planned Batch Order | 2,266,213 |
| May-2023 | Production | 593,712 |
| May-2023 | Projected On hand Stock |  |

I want to change the current formula of the **Projected On Hand Stock** to new formula.

**Old Formula**.
Projected On hand Stock = On Hand + Max(Production,Planned Batch Order) - Max(Sales Order,Demand Forecast)

```
REQ_QTY_GROUP = 
VAR MONTHYEAR =
    MAX ( DIM_REQTRANS[MONTHYEAR] )
VAR REFTYPE =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DIM_REQTRANSREFTYPE[REFTYPEENUM] )
VAR GROUPITEM = SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_REQTRANS[ITEMGROUP])
VAR CUM_PLANNED =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( DIM_REQTRANS[REQQTY] ),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DIM_REQTRANS), DIM_REQTRANS[REFTYPEENUM] = "Planned Batch Order" && DIM_REQTRANS[MONTHYEAR] <= MONTHYEAR && DIM_REQTRANS[ITEMGROUP] = GROUPITEM
    ))
VAR CUM_PRODUCTION =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( DIM_REQTRANS[REQQTY] ),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DIM_REQTRANS), DIM_REQTRANS[REFTYPEENUM] = "Production" && DIM_REQTRANS[MONTHYEAR] = MONTHYEAR && DIM_REQTRANS[ITEMGROUP] = GROUPITEM
    ))
VAR CUM_DEMANDFORECAST =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( DIM_REQTRANS[REQQTY] ),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DIM_REQTRANS), DIM_REQTRANS[REFTYPEENUM] = "Demand Forecast" && DIM_REQTRANS[MONTHYEAR] = MONTHYEAR && DIM_REQTRANS[ITEMGROUP] = GROUPITEM
    ))
VAR CUM_SALESORDER =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( DIM_REQTRANS[REQQTY] ),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DIM_REQTRANS), DIM_REQTRANS[REFTYPEENUM] = "Sales Order" && DIM_REQTRANS[MONTHYEAR] = MONTHYEAR && DIM_REQTRANS[ITEMGROUP] = GROUPITEM
    ))
VAR CUM_ONHAND =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( DIM_REQTRANS[REQQTY] ),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DIM_REQTRANS), DIM_REQTRANS[REFTYPEENUM] = "On-Hand" && DIM_REQTRANS[MONTHYEAR] <= MONTHYEAR && DIM_REQTRANS[ITEMGROUP] = GROUPITEM
    ))
VAR CUM = IF(CUM_PLANNED > CUM_PRODUCTION,CUM_ONHAND + CUM_PLANNED - IF(CUM_DEMANDFORECAST > CUM_SALESORDER,CUM_DEMANDFORECAST,CUM_SALESORDER),CUM_ONHAND + CUM_PRODUCTION - IF(CUM_DEMANDFORECAST > CUM_SALESORDER,CUM_DEMANDFORECAST,CUM_SALESORDER))
VAR RESULT = 
    IF (
        REFTYPE = "PROJECTED ON HAND STOCK",
        CUM,
        sum(DIM_REQTRANS[REQQTY])
    )
RETURN     
    RESULT
```

**New Fomula:**

Projected On hand Stock = **If** REQDATEMONTHYEAR = "Back Order"
**then** On Hand + Max(Production,Planned Batch Order)
- Max(Sales Order,Demand Forecast)
**else** Projected On hand Stock
+ Max(Production,Planned Batch Order)
- Max(Sales Order,Demand Forecast)

Ex: Projected On hand Stock

Back Order =  3,420,392 + 0 - 0 = 3,420,392

Apr  = (Back Order) 3,420,392 + Max(Production,Planned Batch Order) 247,744 - Max(Sales Order,Demand Forecast) 258,480 = 3,409,593

May = (Apr)3,409,593 + Max(Production,Planned Batch Order) 2,266,213 - Max(Sales Order,Demand Forecast) 3,908,480 = 4,506,681